# How to create single site session variables?

Tags: php, session

Each time I gave a new version of my project to our tester then he placed the new project within a new root folder ( a new site then ). Inside the php files there are `session` variables which are created and used. So the problem comes when he opens two sites at the same time to compare the two releases : with the first site he opens a page , then a `session` variable is created. Now he opens the second site and go to a particular page then he is directly redirected to a particular page because of the `session` variable from the previous site. So how to create site-independent `session` variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporate the folder name into your session variable as a prefix.

Something like:

```
$session_prefix = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'_';
$_SESSION[$session_prefix.'myIdentifier'] = ...
```

Would require a bit more logic if you run scripts which are residing in subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

> So how to create site-independent session variables ?

Use different domains for your sites, not folders as you do now. Use different name (key) for your session variable.

Comment: can you give examples please ?

Comment: and how to make it dynamic ?